How to groupby by array columns in Postgresql (typeorm)
In my Entity I have Column
  @Column({ type: 'jsonb', default: [] })
  solutionFormats: Array<SolutionFormats>;

where
export enum SolutionFormats {
  VIDEO = 'VIDEO',
  IMAGE = 'IMAGE',
  LATEX = 'LATEX',
}

I want to do grouping by values in this solutionFormats column and count results, i.e. if  I have 2 rows whith solutionFormats being [LATEX, VIDEO], [LATEX], the output should be {LATEX: 2, VIDEO: 1}. How to do it? I have already a proplerly filtered queryBuilder object and I want to do this grouping on solutionFormats column.

Advice: Don't use arrays in your data model, stick to a straight forward 3NF model. Relational database are highly optimized for 3NF

So I should create another table with only these three rows? That was what I was thinking about but wasnt sure whether its a good idea

Yes! That is a much better idea and much, much better working with. Suggestion: Study some on data normalization.

Most likely 2 tables, just read about database normalization and check your current data model. Arrays can be useful in rare exceptions and using them shouldn't be your starting point.
